# How to convert byte[] that come from server as text to bitmap ?

Tags: android, xml

In my application i need to get some data from server using http. 
The data that i get is in xml.
one of this data fields is bitmap that suppose to come from the server as byte[].

Now, i scanning the xml and i see that the object type is Text - and i dont know how to convert is to bitmap.

How to solve this ?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Does the server send the binary data as base64 encoded text? Can you please clarify? AFAIK it's not possible to send pure binary through http.

Comment: Of course is text, xml are text documents. First you need to identify how the data was encoded. Base64 is frequently used, but it may have been encoded with any other encoding scheme. It may even have been sent as plain UTF-8 text.

Comment: @Manish Gupta That is not true. HTTP connections always transport binary data. MIME types are optional and they are only to identify the payload type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
byte[] imageAsBytes = Base64.decode(myImageData.getBytes());
Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageAsBytes , 0, imageAsBytes.length);
```

Hope this may help to you.

Answer (score 1):

Use `BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray()` method:

```
byte[] dataFromSrvr = //data from server
Bitmap bmp=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(dataFromSrvr ,0,dataFromSrvr.length);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        entity = null;
        httpGet = new HttpGet(path);
        response = httpclient.execute(httpGet);
        if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
            entity = response.getEntity();
        }
        byte[] imageBytes= EntityUtils.toByteArray(entity);
        Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageBytes , 0, imageBytes.length);
```